# What's the difference between :include_blank and :prompt in the Rails select helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

[In the Rails docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#label-Options), the first two listed options for the `select` helper are `:include_blank` and `:prompt`. I've just realized that I'm using both in my code, but they seem to be interchangeable. Can anyone explain the difference? It's not clear to me from reading the docs.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Main difference is:

```
include_blank: true
```

will render a blank option but

```
prompt: true
```

will execute

```
I18n.translate('helpers.select.prompt', :default => 'Please select')
```

Comment: Yep, that looks like the right answer. I guess semantically, the idea is to use `include_blank` when "nothing" is an acceptable submission, and `prompt` when the first option is not meant to be selected, but is literally a 'prompt'.

Comment: There's a bit more to it than this. If a relationship is already set, then `prompt` will **not** include a blank option. `include_blank`, on the other hand, will always provide that blank option.

Comment: "If a relationship is already set, then prompt will not include a blank option.  "is only for `select` but `select_tag`

Comment: @Ashitaka How do I include blank with prompt, eg. I want to set gender 'male', 'female', 'both'. And if 'male' is already set use should be able to set the gender back to 'both'.

Comment: You probably want to use `prompt` instead of `include_blank` _because_ of the behaviour mentioned in the above comment. More info: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/138578/should-a-blank-option-always-be-included-in-select-inputs