# How to make a drop-list selection mandatory excluding the blank value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my code, i have the following drop list

```
<%= f.collection_select :manufacturer_id, @manufacturers, :id,
            :name,{include_blank: "Select manufacturer",  required: true}, {class: "form-control"} %>
```

Somehow the blank is accepted as a selection. Is there a way to prevent this? I want the user to select a value form the drop-list, except for the blank.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you have a presence validator in your model?

Comment: no, I try to avoid that way

Comment: I would argue that you cannot ensure that the user selected anything and send anything useful to the server if you do not validate in your model on the server or/and add a foreign constraint to your database that the record actually exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Required is an html parameter. Try:

```
<%= f.collection_select :manufacturer_id, @manufacturers, :id,
            :name,{include_blank: "Select manufacturer"}, {class: "form-control",  required: true} %>
```

Comment: Also, `prompt` may be more appropriate for your case than `include_blank`. Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11302728/whats-the-difference-between-include-blank-and-prompt-in-the-rails-select-hel#11304099

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I will also check out promts, thanks for the advice